# "Upload to" vs. "upload on"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, programming

Which preposition should follow the verb *to upload* — *to*, *on*, or something else?

Comment: Upload the file to YouTube.  Upload the file on Tuesday.  Upload the file over Spring Break.  Upload the file under duress.  Maybe you can think of more prepositions to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally you "upload to" and "download from".

You might express that you "uploaded from your laptop to your server", which uses both *from* and *to*.

You might say that you "can do the upload on that machine in the corner", but that refers to the machine you performed the command to upload on (the one physically in front of you), not the one you uploaded to (often the one uploaded from, but not necessarily).

Comment: Your last example sounds to me like the machine you execute the command on. For example you could upload to and from another machine but perform such processes ON the machine in the corner

Comment: @mplungjan You are correct, it would be common for the machine uploaded *from* to be the one uploaded *on*, but it doesn't necessarily follow. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: But wouldn't you write "The ZIP folder is now uploaded onto/into your FTP", considering the fact that at that point said ZIP folder would have already reached its destination and therefore figure on/in said FTP, however "virtually" so?