# File kept on/at the server?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I want to write that I have saved the file on the server. What should I write, *on* the server or *at* the server?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! :-) I have a question for you. Why did you say initially, "I have saved the file on the server?"

Also, are you familiar with our English Language Learners site? You can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "**on** the server" is correct. It is difficult to explain the collocational significance of prepositions to a non-native speaker, esp., a learner. That is, I can't tell you why it should be *on* and why not *at*, right now.

Answer (score 4):

> You are saving files *in* the memory.
>
> You are saving files *to* a storage device (flash drive, memory
> stick, CD).
>
> You are saving files *on* or *to* a server.

So far, these are my experiences from reading various IT articles and documentations. I agree with Kris with the difficulty of explaining *why*. But I'm pretty sure that these are correct to the best of my knowledge.

Saving files to a server is tantamount to *uploading* files to it. There's a good explanation from this [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101048/upload-to-vs-upload-on).

> You *upload* to the server.
>
> You *download* from the server.

Having these said, I would recommend using *to* rather than *on*, but still I cannot explain this more precisely.

Comment: I've never heard "to the server" after decades in IT.

Comment: "To the server" sounds entirely natural to me.

Answer (score 3):

In American english parlance, files are saved "On" the server, not "to" it.  They can be sent "to" a server, but they are kept/saved "on" it.  I suspect that there is an inferred clause that's been omitted.  The full statement ought to be, "the files are being saved on the server's hard drive",  but over time the "hard drive" part has been dropped.

Answer (score 2):

It must be *on*, because *on* connotes the motion of the file, at one place, being transferred to the server to be saved. To save the file *at* the server, it would have to already be there, in which case it would already be saved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question because could be correct depending on the context.

If you have a server that you can access via the Finder in OS X or similar mechanism, I would say I am saving a file on the server, onto the server, or to the server. To be honest, onto the server would be most correct but probably the least used since it implies movement to. A reasonable distinction is whether you are copying or moving.

If I were ssh'd into a server and I were saving a file, I would be saving it at the server or on the server.