# Is there any scenario where one would use 'in the server' rather than 'on the server'?

Tags: prepositions, technical

My sentence is 'The user should be created on the server.' OR 'The user should be created in the server.' I usually use 'on' in all cases but I am wondering if the act of creation is better described by 'in': 'The user should be created in the server. Their details will be saved 'on' the server.' I did search for answers so I hope this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Related question, [File kept on/at the server?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142663/file-kept-on-at-the-server).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a scenario in which "in" would be better: the scenario of crawling inside a server in order to procreate someone you will establish as a user.  Otherwise, the preposition English speakers use to describe establishing a user's network profile that a server houses is "on": the user is created "on" the server.

Comment: :-) Thanks. It's just that so many people seem to use 'in', one begins to think perhaps one is missing something.

Comment: I was going to suggest that if you spilled your coffee into the server, and someone said *Where's your coffee?*, it would be perfectly correct to say *in the server*.

Comment: @WS2 : Yes, that would certainly be "in" the server.  I only hope you didn't accidentally burn those in there who were procreating.