# Which is correct? uploaded to or uploaded on

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

Attached please find all the documents that I have uploaded on my cloud so far.

or

Attached please find all the documents that I have uploaded to my cloud so far.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 
 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101048/upload-to-vs-upload-on

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Denver!

I like *to*.

But is it *my* cloud or *the* cloud?